# How can I disable the Cmd-G 'Add Image' shortcut in the editor?

Tags: bug, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Much to my chagrin, I've discovered that the question/answer editor view implements a keyboard shortcut of Cmd-G (on OS X, can't speak to other platforms) for adding images to posts. I'm sure this is very useful for folks who add lots of images to their posts, but for my part, I *far* more often want to use the OS X platform-standard text searching command, "Find Next", that is normally bound to Cmd-G.

Is there a way to turn off this "override" behavior? (And preferably any other overrides of platform-standard key bindings related to text editing?)

Comment: Same with PC, Ctrl+G is bound.

Comment: Anyway, no such way exists, so closing as dupe of the existing feature request asking to add such option.

Comment: I always click outside the editor window first; same applies to CMD-R (reload the page) for example.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to find text within the editor. Sounds like the answer is "solve this yourself" unfortunately.

Comment: For the record, although I don't disagree that this is a dupe of the more general request, I think that asking for the editor to not clobber major platform standard key bindings that appear as key equivalents in menus is a lot more "reasonable" than asking that it not clobber all the quasi-invisible emacs key bindings that happen to work, but don't appear as menu key equivalents. Maybe I'll open a separate question that makes that distinction...